# Playwright executing code in a weird order using Fixtures and Page Object Model (playwright nodejs)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, playwright

I'm trying to learn how to use Fixtures with Playwright.  I've followed playwrights documentation and various tutorials to come up with a very basic set of tests running fixtures.  If I have the same test:

1. Using built in test fixture from @playwright/test

   1a) Test execution runs as expected when stepping through the code
2. Using custom Fixture overriding test from @playwright test

   2a) Test appears to hit breakpoints out of order

   2b) Hit random js files where there weren't even breakpoints in the first place (transport.js, instrumentation.js, and others).

I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding how fixtures work, or missing something else in my basic setup?  I've double and triple checked for missing awaits, but nothing stands out (nor do I think it's the issue since there is no bouncing around without custom fixtures).

Sample code:
POM #1

```
export class HomePage //etc...
constructor(page:Page) { this.page = page }

async goto() {
    await this.page.goto('/');
}
```

POM #2

```
export class SearchPage // etc...
constructor(page:Page) { this.page = page }

async performSearch() {
    await this.page.locator('#firstname').fill('Firstname');
    await this.page.locator('#lastname').fill('Lastname');
    await this.page.locator('button:has-text("Search")').click();
}
```

Fixture:

```
import { test as baseTest } from '@playwright/test'
import { HomePage } from './page-objects/home-page'
import { SearchPage } from './page-objects/search-page'

const test = baseTest.extend({
    home: HomePage;
    search: SearchPage;
}>({
    home: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new HomePage(page));
    },
    search: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new SearchPage(page));
    }
});
export default test;
```

Test #1 (Working Without custom fixtures)

```
let home: HomePage;
let search: SearchPage;
test('Quick search', async ({page}) => {
    home = new HomePage(page);
    search = new SearchPage(page);
    await home.goto();
    await searchPage.performSearch();
    // expect(etc...)
});
```

Test #2 (With custom fixtures - impossible to debug and bouncing all over the place)

```
import test { home, search } from './Fixtures/baseTest'

test('Quick search', async ({ home, search}) => {
    await home.goto();
    await searchPage.performSearch();
    // expect(etc...)
});
```

I thought I came up with a pretty neat framework for my more complex test solution, but started bouncing all over the place when debugging; so I created this very simple example to make sure I didn't miss anything and still bounce all over the place.

In the first test using built in test fixture, if I break on home.goto(), it works as you'd expect.  I break there, can step into/over, and it goes where you expect.

In the second test using my custom fixtures, I have a breakpoint on home.goto().  When I debug, I never hit that breakpoint.  Instead it takes me into the goto function where I don't have a breakpoint.  Then if I step over that I hit the initial breakpoint (after it already executed the goto method).  Then if I step over again, it takes me to those random js files (transport, instrumentation, even others).  Eventually I just F5 to continue, and it again just hits breakpoints out of order.

In the end, I think it's doing what it's supposed to, but my concern is jumping all over the place when trying to write actual complex tests.  If I can't step into functions I need to debug, or it executes out of order this would be impossible.

If anyone has any thoughts/ideas what's going on, it would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know if I can provide any more information or clarify my question/concern any more :)